# Selenium - Error getting WebElement within iFrame

Tags: html, selenium, iframe, automated-tests

I am building a small automated test script with Selenium Chrome WebDriver last version, but now I am facing an issue when I try to get a WebElement within an iFrame, even when I switch to it.

This is the way HTML is built:

[image: HTML part]

As you can check, there is another page "encrusted" inside iFrame, and the button is defined below (it's the part I selected):

[image: Inner Button]

This is the way I am using to get the WebElement (obviously failing):

```
WebElement frameAperturar = 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@title='Aperturar']"));

driver.switchTo().frame(frameAperturar);

asociarSiniestroButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Asociar Siniestro']"));
asociarSiniestroButton.click();
```

This is the exception I got when I tried to get the WebElement:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@aria-label='Asociar Siniestro']"}
```

(Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)

Do you know how I can get an element of the page inside the iFrame after I switch to the frame?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: This is the exception I got: "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@aria-label='Asociar Siniestro']"}
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

Comment: updated my anwer

Answer (score 2):

You can actually select an iFrame using the below methods:

- frame(index)
- frame(Name of Frame [or] Id of the frame)
- frame(WebElement frameElement)
- defaultContent()

So you can switch by passing the any above information about the frame. Yes you need to switch every time according to require action.

Example:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);

driver.SwitchTo().Frame("top");
```

.... Perform your action on frame

```
driver.SwitchTo().defaultContent();

driver.SwitchTo().Frame("navigation");
```

.... Perform your action on frame

```
driver.SwitchTo().defaultContent();
```

Try below XPath

```
//span[@class='apexButtonText' and contains(.,'Asociar Siniestro')]
```

OR

```
//span[contains(text(),'Asociar Siniestro')]
```

OR

```
//span[@class='apexButtonText'][contains(text(),'Asociar Siniestro')]
```

OR

```
//button[@aria-label='Asociar Siniestro']//span[contains(.,'Asociar Siniestro')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to selenium but seems like your button is actually 'span' and xpath wont work like this, try `//span[contains(text(),'Asociar Siniestro')]`

Comment: He do have a button with same class so his xpath is correct but may be the control of click may be not that element and hence your xpath can work

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath

```
//span[@class='apexButtonText'][contains(text(),'Asociar Siniestro')]
```